# jQuery persistent non-event bindings

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 var $thingy = $('.thingy'),
     $window = $(window);

 $window.on('resize', function(){
       thingy.width($window.width()/12);
 });
```

Is it possible to add more `.thingy`s to the page and have them resize without re-querying?

I am aware that the following will work:

```
 var $window = $(window);

 $window.on('resize', function(){
       $('.thingy').width($window.width()/12);
 });
```

the problem is, I am not adding `.thingy`s to the page very often, making the creation of new jQuery objects and rapid re-querying of the DOM seem like alot of overhead.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you add a new `.thingy`, update the selection with

```
$thingy = $('.thingy');
```

or

```
$thingy = $thingy.add(the_new_thingy)
```

Of course `$thingy` must be visible in both places.

Comment: According to the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/add/), "*the .add() method constructs a new jQuery object*". Yet that was my first thought, too...

Comment: Too bad jQuery doesn't seem to support appending to the existing object. It makes a jQuery object as a reference type less usable.

Comment: Still this means I wont have to re-construct-re-query for each resize event, it allows me to add and re-construct as needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply reassign to the variable:

```
var $window = $(window),
    $thingy = $('.thingy');
$window.on('resize', function(){
    $thingy.width($window.width()/12);
});


// then sometime:
$thingy = $('.thingy');
// or:
$thingy = $thingy.add(elements)
```